# Tango project, rooting

Tags: performance, root, tango

I made an export button on Tango and trying to export the file, but I have a problem. I tried to debug but in some cases it doesn't work. So by searching the internet,  I figured out that I have to root the tango. Therefore, I installed the Super SU, but it does work. It says 'no binary SU' .
I downloaded CF auto root and I know the way to boot load. But, I don't know what to do from now on.
I am trying to Fast root but I don't know. Any Help? Please~    ﻿

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take some time to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then show us some code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be a root in order to write a file with Project Tango tablet. Like any android apps, a write permissions is sufficient :

If you still having problems, please tell us more how are you trying to write a file.